# Запуск правила Makefile не в текущей папке

Tags: makefile

**Есть следующая иерархия в рабочей директории:**

```
config (directory)
main.cpp
Makefile
```

**содержимое Makefile в рабочей директории:**

```
main: main.o
    g++ -Wall -std=c++1y main.o ./config/load_config.o -o main
main.o: config/load_config.o
    g++ -Wall -std=c++1y -o main.o -c main.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o
```

**в директории config лежит:**

```
load_config.cpp
load_config.h
Makefile
```

**содержимое config/Makefile**

```
load_config.o: load_config.cpp
    g++ -Wall -std=c++1y -o load_config.o -c load_config.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o
```

если рабочая директория config, то *config/Makefile* выполняется без ошибок. В результате имеем файл *config/load_config.o*. Делаем *cd ../*  После этого выполняем make в главной директории программу собирается нормально. Но если отсутствует *config/load_config.o*, то программа уже не собирается. Вопрос в следующем как изменить главный Makefile, чтобы он сначала выполнял make в папке config(собирал *config/load_config.o*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы примерно так переделал:

```
main: main.o config/load_config.o
    g++ -Wall -std=c++1y $^ -o $@
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -std=c++1y -o $@ -c $<
config/load_config.o:
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)
clean:
    rm *.o
```

пояснения:

- `$^` — список всех пререквизитов
- `$<` — первый пререквизит
- `$@` — цель правила
- `$(MAKE) -C каталог цель` — [один из рекомендованных способов](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html) вызова программы *gnu/make* рекурсивно в *каталоге*
- `$(@D)` — когда цель представлена в виде `каталог/файл`, возвращает `каталог`
- `$(@F)` — когда цель представлена в виде `каталог/файл`, возвращает `файл`

Comment: main.o: config/load_config.o а данная строка о чём говорит? Это зависимость от файла или зависимость от правила?

Comment: `main.o: config/load_config.o`: как и в любом правиле, это зависимость цели (в данном случае — `main.o`) от пререквизита (`config/load_config.o`). я это ваше правило немного изменил, потому что, по-моему, оно у вас было написано нелогично.

Comment: в главном Makefile оно вообще отсутствовало. Я думала, что таким образом будет запущено правило из Makefile в папке config. То есть в главном Makefile необходимо добавлять цели для всех зависимостей из поддиректорий. Вроде дошло. Спасибо.